# How to convert .class file (Selenium Script) to .jmx file (JMeter Script)

Tags: selenium, jmeter, file-conversion, typeconverter

I have an SLA from one of the clients from my organization, We have to test their application by following methods only,

**Either** we have to do an automation test script (**using Selenium**) and convert those test scripts to performance test scripts (**to JMeter**)

**Nor** we have to do a performance test script (**using JMeter**) and convert those test scripts to an automation test script (**to Selenium**)

Please let me know if there is any other simple method (Separate tool or Plugins) to convert any one of the test scripts to the other one.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

1. Conversion from JMeter to Selenium is not possible (at least currently with JMeter 5.3 and Selenium 3)
2. [Conversion from Selenium to JMeter is possible](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-selenium-scripts-jmx-converter) (up to certain extent), you need to:

   - Start JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)
   - Configure Selenium to use JMeter as the [proxy](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/http_proxies/)
   - Run your Selenium tests via JMeter proxy
   - JMeter will convert Selenium tests into [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers

   You will need to perform [correlation of the dynamic parameters and parameterization](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of at least credentials

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion. Here I am seeking any options to convert existing selenium script that needs to be converted to JMeter script. Is there any other way/tool to do so? Please suggest int his way.